# Complement Set of Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a hard time knowing what it means for a thing to be a complement of a cartesian coordinate.

So let's say I have the arbitrary non empty sets $A$ and $B$:
$$ (A \times B)^c$$

does this equal the individual parts:
$$(A \times B)^c = A^c \times B^c?$$

If so then why?

Comment: What is your universe?  $(A \times B)^c$ doesn't make sense unless you know what your universal set is.

Comment: just edited the question. A and B are arbitrary non empty sets

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary non-empty sets *where*?  What is the universe that $A$ and $B$ live in?  Do they live in the same universe?  What is $A^c$?  What is $B^c$?

Comment: what do you mean? A and B are arbitrary sets

Comment: If $A$ is an "arbitrary set", then what is $A^c$?

Comment: well so if x is an element in A and y is an element in B then x would not be an element of the complement of A right? So I am not understanding how you could prove or disprove the statement above using x and y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65462/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-user510).

Answer (score 18):

Assume $A{\times}B\subseteq X{\times}Y$ and so using set builder notation: $$A{\times}B = \{(x,y)\in X{\times}Y\mid x\in A~\wedge~ y\in B\}$$

Due to de Morgan's Laws of Dual Negation, the complement (relative to $X{\times}Y$) would therefore be : $$(A{\times}B)^{\complement_{X{\times}Y}} = \{(x,y)\in X{\times}Y\mid x\notin A~\vee~ y\notin B\}$$

Thus we have $$(A{\times}B)^{\complement_{X{\times}Y}} = (A^{\complement_X}{\times}Y) \cup (X{\times}B^{\complement_Y})$$

Comment: why you don't conclude that: $A x B^c=(A^c x B^c)\cup(A^c x B)\cup(A x B^c)$

Comment: I think in the last line, you did a mistake,, in the last it would be $A^{c} \times B^{c}$

Answer (score 12):

Typically,
$$ (A\times B)^{c} \ne A^c \times B^c. $$
For example, suppose that $A = B = [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  Then $A \times B$ is the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The complement of the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the Euclidean plane with a square shaped hole near the origin.  On the other hand,
$$A^c = B^c = \mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1] = (-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty).$$
Then $A^c \times B^c$ ends up being the Euclidean plane, minus a "cross" that is centered near the origin.  Specifically, it is the set of points
$$ \{ (x,y) : (x < 0 \text{ or } x > 1) \text{ and } (y < 0 \text{ or } y > 1) \}.$$
This is *not* the same as the plane minus a square, and so $(A\times B)^c$ is not equal to $A^c \times B^c$.

Answer (score 5):

When considering subsets of $X{\times}Y$, then for all not empty $S,A \subseteq X~$ and for all not empty $T,B \subseteq Y$, we have that the *relative* complement of the cartesian product is:

$$S{\times}T ~\smallsetminus~ A{\times}B ~=~ (S \smallsetminus A){\times}T ~\cup~ S{\times}(T \smallsetminus B)$$