# Proof of Complement of Cartesian Products for subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Im currently looking for a proof that shows that the following statement is true:

$(M \times N)^{\mathrm{C}}=\left(M^{\mathrm{C}} \times Y\right) \cup\left(X \times N^{\mathrm{C}}\right)$

Where M is a subset of X and N is a subset of Y.

Would be nice if someone could show me the proof because im not getting anywhere myself currently.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider the universe of $\mathbb N^2$, $M,N,X,Y=2\mathbb N$. Note that $(1,1)\in\mathbb N^2\setminus(2\mathbb N)^2$, but it is not in $(\mathbb N\setminus2\mathbb N)\times2\mathbb N$ nor in $\mathbb N\times(\mathbb N\setminus2\mathbb N)$.

Comment: Currently we are just talking about Natural Numbers so it just has to be true for those

Comment: @LucaBarden It's still not true. I can easily construct a counterexample there too. Where did you get this claim. Also, that's the kind of information that you should include in a question.

Comment: We had to find a correct representation of (M x N)^c as a Join of Cartesian Products of M,N aswell as their complements and prove it

Comment: @LucaBarden All I'm saying is, what you've done here is wrong.

Comment: Did you get what representation i had to construct and prove? If yes could you show me how its done then? I've got that one from this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426115/complement-set-of-cartesian-product

Comment: Not quite.  The *universe* of $\mathbb N$ is a different thing than the universe of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.  After all.  $6\not \in \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ so $6 \not \in M\times N$ so is or is not $6 \in (M\times N)^c$.  But not if we assume our universe is $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

Comment: @fleablood How exactly does one canonically embed a cross product of sets in the naturals?

Comment: @LucaBarden You misread the answer there. They said that $X\times Y$ was the universe.

Comment: Tbh im german so i dont know all the english terms of this so i just tried to do my best. sry

Comment: I'm not criticizing you, just saying that the math is wrong.

Comment: So is there a possible proof to that statement or not?

Comment: This is true if $X$ is the universe which $M$ is a subset of and $Y$ is the universe which $N$ is a subset of and $X\times Y$ is the univers which $M\times N$ is a subset of, and therefore that $M^c = X\setminus M$ and $N^c=Y\setminus N$ nad $(M\times N)^c = (X\times Y)\setminus (M\times N)$.  In other words $(X\times Y)\setminus(M\times N)=((X\setminus M)\times Y)\cup (X\times (Y\setminus N))$.

Comment: "How exactly does one canonically embed a cross product of sets in the naturals? "  One doesn't.  That was my point.  The universe of $(M\times N)^c$ is implied to be $X\times Y$ but when refering to $M^c \times Y$ presumably the universe of $M^c$ is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to define what $X^c$ means in terms of "universes".  After all $babartheelephant \not \in M\times N$  but does it make sense to say $babartheelephant \in (M\times N)^c$?

For that matter $6\not \in M\times N$ because $6$ is not an ordered pair. Does that mean $6\in (M\times N)^c$?

So $(M\times N)^c \subset  X \times  Y$ as $(M\times N)^c = \{(a,b)|a\in X, b\in Y$ but is not the case that $a\in M$ and $b\in N\}$.

ANd $M^c = \{x\in X|x\not \in M\}$ and $N^c = \{y\in Y|y\not \in N\}$.

.....

So

If $(x,y) \in (M\times N)^c$ then it is not the case that $x\in M$ and $y\in N$.  So either $x \not \in M$ or $y\not \in N$.  Or in other words $x\in M^c$ or $y\in N^c$.  Or in other words $x \in M^c$ and $y$ could be anything in $Y$, or $y\in N^c$ and $x$ could be anything in $M$.  So either $(x,y)\in M^c\times Y$ or $(x,y) \in X\times N^c$.

So $(x,y) \in (M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)$ and so $(M\times N)^c \subseteq (M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)$.

And if $(x,y) \in (M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)$ then either $(x,y) \in M^c \times Y$ or $(x,y) \in X\times N^c$ (or both).

If $(x, y)\in M^c \times Y$ then$x \in M^c$ so  $x \not\in M$ and $(x,y) \not \in M\times N$  so $(x,y) \in (M\times N)^c$.  And if $(x,y) \in X\times N^c$ then $y\in N^c$ so $y\not \in N$ and $(x,y) \not\in M\times N$ so $(x,y) \in (M\times N)^c$.

So $(x,y) \in (M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)\implies (x,y)\in (M\times N)^c$.

So $ (M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)\subseteq (M\times N)^c$

So $(M\times N)^c=(M^c\times Y)\cup (X \times N^c)$